Remove ?utm_source=web-stories-generator and ?feed_id=1816&_unique_id=65de7f2c860c8
My website generates URLs like this: xxxx.com/abc/?utm_source=web-stories-generator
xxxx.com/abc/feed_id=xxxx&_unique_id=xxxx
How can I remove ?utm_source=web-stories-generator and ?feed_id=1816&_unique_id=65de7f2c860c8 from these URLs?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hello Mr. Max,
This looks to me like Google Ad campaign URLs that are generated there. Do you have any campaigns running within Google Ads that need to be disabled?
